# Load images after page load

Tags: jquery, load

I have a problem with image loading. 
I tried to use `load()`, but it didn't work:

```
$().load('/wp-content/uploads/--/--/image1.jpg');
$().load('/wp-content/uploads/--/--/image2.jpg');
$().load('/wp-content/uploads/--/--/image3.jpg');
```

I wrote js slider which change background in div.
Images are quite big (more than 100kB). I change background every 10 sec. And when I go to this website for 1st time, every time background is changing it's blank space while loading image, until all images were used as background.

How can I load images using jquery so even if I view the website for 1st time browser would load those images from cache.

**Update**

Slider change div background: `$(this).css("background-image","image.jpg");`, so I cant use `append`, i cant use `<img src="' + image[i] + '" .. />`. I just want to load images to cache, so when I background will change, image will be already loaded.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery

Comment: can you please have a look on update. thx

Answer (score 2):

You can have an array of image names, and append them after the page has loaded...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var images = ["img/image-1.jpg", "img/image-2.jpg"];
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        $("#slider-selector").append("<img src=\"" + images[i] + "\" />");
    }
});
```

Comment: append the images and then remove them after they've been appended... so if you apply them to a hidden element then remove that element on page load